# Why is my meta reputation lower on meta.math.SE?

Tags: support, reputation

I notice it's 10 points lower on meta.math.SE.

Comment: See [How long is the time of the transfer of the reputation value from the main to the meta site?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6721/how-long-is-the-time-of-the-transfer-of-the-reputation-value-from-the-main-to-th)